# phpmyadmin only displays internal relation in relational view

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to setup foreign key for my mysql database using phpmyadmin.
But phpmyadmin only displays internal relation in 'relational view'. Note I have already made sure of following steps.

1. Setup phpmyadmin database (create_table.sql and config stuff)
   [image: phpmyadmin status]
2. Made sure all tables in my database using InnoDb
   [image: Inno db]
3. Made sure my intended foreign keys/reference Keyes are indexed.
   [image]

After all these steps I can only see internal relations in my relational view.
[image: Problem]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not actually a solution, but since I cannot comment on posts yet, I'll add a few comments that might help.

I've faced this same issue and the **critical parameters** seem to be the following:

1. Case insensitive operating system (in my case windows)
2. Mixed-case table names (e.g. "TableName")

I've been using Mixed-case table names successfully in Linux, but in Windows something seems to go really wrong with phpMyAdmin.

I bet your table names are mixed-case. Try creating a test table yourself, with a fully lowercase name, and check if you see the "Foreign Key Relations" options of phpMyAdmin.

If you do, then we've found the source of the problem and we're just left with finding a solution or workaround for it :)

ps: More on case-sensitivity and mysql, without any hints about phpMyAdmins view on all of this, can be found here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

This IS the solution. Renaming table name 'myTable' to 'my_table' solves the problem.
[image: Renaming table]

Comment: I confirm both: case insensitive operating system(MacOS HFS+), mixed-case table names(bookTable). Yet I need to verify using all lowercase name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different storage engines on the tables in your database, this would be the case. The only storage engine I know to support foreign keys is InnoDB. MyISAM  and the rest don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Storage Engine to: `innoDB` and then click save.[image]